# Assets modal window in publish form is blank when I click Add Files

Tags: assets, matrix, modal

Doing some testing on a local version of a website, trying to implement an Assets upload field in a Matrix column. When in the publish form and I click the "Add Files" button the modal pops up but it is blank. I do get a console error in Chrome dev tools...

=========================================

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://condley-intranet.dev/. Origin http://condley-banking.dev is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined assets.min.js:8

qq.FileUploader assets.min.js:8

Assets.FileManager.Garnish.Base.extend.init assets.min.js:8

Garnish.Base.a.extend.constructor garnish-0.1.min.js:18

h.constructor garnish-0.1.min.js:14

h.constructor garnish-0.1.min.js:14

(anonymous function) assets.min.js:8

d jquery.js:39

b.extend.each jquery.js:37

b.fn.b.each jquery.js:30

c.ajax.complete jquery.js:161

p jquery.js:43

l.fireWith jquery.js:44

d jquery.js:167

b jquery.js:178

=========================================

I'm using the Assets/Matrix combo on a MSM site. The "main" site is "condley-banking.dev". The MSM site is "condley-intranet.dev". I'm logged in to the CP through the "condley-banking.dev" site and then selected the MSM site from the CP dropdown. I thought this info might help after reading the error, but it's al lover my head. Thanks for any information!

Comment: If I login to the Control Panel of the MSM site url instead of the "main" url I get a little farther, but it's still not working completely. I can see the Upload Files button, the search bar, and the display option buttons. But when I try and upload it acts like it uploads, but doesn't display anything in the modal.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the dev console when loading the Modal? Also, can you add your version information for Assets, Matrix, and EE? Thank you!

Comment: No errors this time :/ Assets v2.0.5, Matrix v.2.5.3, EE v.2.5.5

Comment: I've also triple-checked to make sure the themes folder was uploaded all the way

Comment: Are you using a shared themes folder for the MSM?  What is your themes folder URL in the General Config?

Comment: Lisa, it is a shared theme folder and it's pointing to the "main" site, not the MSM sites.

Comment: Mike, can you try adding: $config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';  to your system/expressionengine/config/config.php and see if that helps?

Comment: Lisa, well I figure out the problem. I had not "Updated Indexes" in the Assets settings. After I did that I could see my upload directories listed in the modal. The file upload worked, and I could see my test file in the folder I setup above root. Woo! I have another issue now with the front-end file url :) but I'll start a new question on SE if you think that would be better...

Comment: Mike, I should have had you look at that first thing.  Thank you for letting me know.  I'd recommend posting it as the answer and accepting that as the official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not "Updated Indexes" in the plugin CP. Afte that things worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Your JS forms look like they're attempting a cross-domain communication:

> HTMLHttpRequest cannot load http://condley-intranet.dev/. Origin http://condley-banking.dev is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Are you able to locate where you're crossing domains and make them consistent? I'd start with your General Config and/or /system/expressionengine/config/

Comment: Lisa, I just made a comment above with some more info...

Comment: Lisa, this just saved my butt. Was missing www and once added all started working again.